# $C(\mathbb{T})$ embed in $B(\mathcal{H})$ for some Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras

I was looking at examples of $C^*$ algebras. If $\mathcal{H}$ is a Hilbert space, then $B(\mathcal{H})$ is a standard example. The space of continuous functions on the unit circle $\mathbb{T}$ (denoted $C(\mathbb{T}) $) is also another example.

I know that we can embed $C(\mathbb T)\subset B(\mathcal H)$ for some Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. Is there a standard choice for $B(\mathcal{H})$ in this case? If not, is $\mathcal{H}$ necessarily infinite dimensional or can we choose it to be so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

I would try $\mathcal{H} = L^2(\mathbb{T})$, and  $C(\mathbb{T})\ni f \mapsto L_f\in B(\mathcal{H})$ the multiplication by $f$.

Comment: ah of course. stupid question: $L^2(\mathbb{T})$ is infinite dimensional, no?

Comment: @chhro: Yes, it is.  An orthonormal basis is $e^{i n t}$, $n \in \mathbb{Z}$  ( the measure should give $\mathbb{T}$ size $1$). And it is an interesting question.  We can change the measure on $\mathbb{T}$ to be just equivalent to the usual one.

Comment: To the OP: More generally, when $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space, then we have an injective $*$-representation
$L: C(X) \hookrightarrow B(L^2(X)): f \mapsto L_f$ where $L_f(g) = fg$ for $f \in C(X), g \in L^2(X)$.

Comment: @orangeskid An injective morphism between $C^*$-algebras always preserves the norm (it is always isometric).

Comment: @QuantumSpace: Yes, indeed, thank you for reminding me that. Now,  we need the measure on $X$ to have support $X$ for injectiveness, right?

Comment: @orangeskid What do you mean with the measure on $X$ to have support?

Comment: Ah I think I get what you mean. Yes, I suppose you are right. There is a canonical choice for measures on a compact group (such as is the case here), which is the Haar measure and for this measure everything works out nicely.

Comment: @QuantumSpace: Yes, the Haar measure on a compact group works great. I think that on every compact space $X$ there are measures with support $X$, fairly easy for separable (i.e. metrisable) compacts.

Comment: @orangeskid I'm no expert on the topic, but one can invoke the fact that Radon probability measures on $C(X)$ correspond to states on $C(X)$ and translate the problem to something purely functional analytic.

Comment: @QuantumSpace: That clarified it! So basically for every $f\ne 0$ there exists a linear functional $L$ on $C(X)$ with $L(f)\ne 0$, and this is a signed measure $\mu$. If $f$ is positive then $|\mu|(f) \ge |\mu(f)| > 0$.  Thank you!